# for them to have left

Tags: meaning, past-tense

a. It was possible for them to have left the house.

What does that sentence mean?

That it was possible that they had already left the house?

or

That they could leave the house, but they didn't.

?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, we are talking about two different uses of **possible** here:

1. The ability or otherwise to do something. "It's possible for Tiger Woods to play a round of golf under par, but it's not possible for me." **Possible/not possible** here has the same meaning as ***can/cannot***.
2. Uncertainty about a fact. "It's possible that the temperature will reach 25 degrees today." **Possible** here has the same meaning as ***might***. "The temperature might reach 25 degrees (or it might not.)"

What about the original sentence?

> It was possible for them to have left the house.

As the sentence stands it could have either meaning. However, the OP's second interpretation, "That they could leave the house, but they didn't" is not quite right. Even if we know they had the **ability** to leave the house, we still wouldn't know whether they **did** leave it.

If I wanted to make clear one or other meanings, I would make some minor edits:

1. It was possible for them to leave the house. (="They were able to leave"; "They could leave")
2. It was possible that they had left the house. (They might have left, or they might not; we don't know.)

Comment: I'm not so sure. Analyzing such an unlikely utterance is a bit of a mug's game anyway, but I think your ***we still wouldn't know whether they did leave it*** seems off. *He could **beat** me at chess* probably implies ***...and he did***, but *He **could have beaten** me* strongly implies ***...but he didn't*** (even though he had the ability). Same applies to OP's ***possible ... to have left*** as regards whether they actually left or not, imho.

Comment: Thank  you both very much. 'It was possible for them to leave' (we don't know what they did). 'It was possible for them to have left' I think should mean it was possible that they had already left (this is not a question of ability) however it seems that native speakers use that sentence sort of instead of 'iIt was possible for them to leave' but probably there is a difference and that is the one FumbleFingers has in mind... But there might also be regional differences.

Comment: Just to be clear. I am lost here. I am trying to clarify things and probably failing miserably. I am not a native speaker. Maybe the sentence is weird. And BTW, 'mug's game' is a very nice expression I had never heard! Thanks!